# I'm looking for a function that is like 'str.isupper()' but with symbols?

Tags: python, string, symbols

I'm looking for a function that can do the exact same like `str.isupper()` but instead with symbols like:

```
symbols = '!@#$%^&*()-_+=`~;:\'[]{}|<>,./?'

foo = '@&(='

# and then a function somewhat like this

print(issymbol(foo)) # this should return true
```

Thanks!

Comment: `all(char in symbols for char in foo)`?

Comment: use `symbols = string.punctuation`. Requires `import string`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a single char, this is simply the `in` operator:

```
print( char in symbols )
```

For a string, use the `all` method:

```
print (all (char in symbols for char in foo) )
```